# Bash - how to replace line specific field seperated by colon delimiter (:)?

Tags: arrays, bash, file, awk, sed

I have a file BookDB.txt which stores data in the following format :

```
Java for dummies:Pauline:10.56:4:3
Bash for dummies:David:10.45:4:5
PHP for dummies:Frederich:10.67:4:4
Perl for dummies:Pearlyn:10.56:4:5
C++ for dummies:Jared:10.46:4:5
```

If I wanted to say, replace the first field of the fourth line with "anything for dummies" such that the file looked exactly like below, how would i do it?

```
Java for dummies:Pauline:10.56:4:3
Bash for dummies:David:10.45:4:5
PHP for dummies:Frederich:10.67:4:4
anything for dummies:Pearlyn:10.56:4:5
C++ for dummies:Jared:10.46:4:5
```

**I've tried the snippets provided by others in this question, but the whitespace in the first field is giving me problems :**

[sed replace in-line a specific column number value at a specific line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557206/sed-replace-in-line-a-specific-column-number-value-at-a-specific-line-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` you can use field separator `:` and target specific row and column:

```
awk -F: 'NR==4{$1="anything for dummies"}1' OFS=: file
Java for dummies:Pauline:10.56:4:3
Bash for dummies:David:10.45:4:5
PHP for dummies:Frederich:10.67:4:4
anything for dummies:Pearlyn:10.56:4:5
C++ for dummies:Jared:10.46:4:5
```

Comment: Not the comma, but the colon... Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: See latest edit, it is there now. I forgot using `OFS=:`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `sed` you probably need to quote your expressions well:

```
sed 's|^Perl for dummies|anything for dummies|' your_file
```

Output:

```
Java for dummies:Pauline:10.56:4:3
Bash for dummies:David:10.45:4:5
PHP for dummies:Frederich:10.67:4:4
anything for dummies:Pearlyn:10.56:4:5
C++ for dummies:Jared:10.46:4:5
```

Adding `-i` option at the beginning of it alters the file directly.

And I'd recommend using `-E` or `-r` if your sed supports it as it's easier. Here you would have needed to quote () with \'s:

```
sed -E 's|^Perl( for dummies)|anything\1|' your_file
```

The command gives same output/result.

Comment: Interesting... How would I use variables in this context? Something like : sed 's|^${OLDTITLE}|${NEWTITLE}|' your_file ?

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo You have to use `""` instead of `''` e.g. `sed "s|^${OLDTITLE}|${NEWTITLE}|" your_file`. I just do hope that your titles would not need to have characters recognizable as regex by sed. If they do, those characters would also need to be quoted. And most of the time it's with \. If not with `[]` e.g. `[.]`.

Comment: While it replaces `Perl for dummies` text with `anything for dummies` but does it solve the stated problem of **replace the first field of the fourth line**? What if `Perl for dummies` text is also present somewhere else in the file?

Comment: @anubhava I actually gave a guess that he was just describing an example about the 4the line. However the main point was *"but the whitespace in the first field is giving me problems"*.

Comment: Actually if I wanted to substitute any field I wanted, wouldn't anubhava's solution be better? Just cant figure out how to use variables properly with his solution. Something like : awk -F: "NR==${LINENUMBER}{$1=${NEWTITLE}}1" OFS=: file ?

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo: If you want operate file on row, column basis then `awk` is the right tool. To use variable in awk command use this **`awk -F: -v line=${LINENUMBER} -v title="${NEWTITLE}" 'NR==line{$1=title}1' OFS=: fie`**

Comment: Nice... It works but when I wanna preserve the changes by overwriting to the file using STDOUT it ends up being blank. Why is that? I use this command : awk -F: -v line=${LINENUMBER} -v title="${NEWTITLE}" 'NR==line{$1=title}1' OFS=: BookDB.txt > BookDB.txt

Comment: Okay I managed to achieve file overwriting, but only through using a temporary file. awk -F: -v line=${TRIMMEDLINENUMBER} -v title="${NEWTITLE}" 'NR==line{$1=title}1' OFS=: BookDB.txt > testfile.tmp && mv testfile.tmp BookDB.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you want the replacement on the 4th line:

```
sed '4s/[^:]*:/anything for dummies:/' input
```

If you want the replacement for the match 'Perl for dummies':

```
sed '/^Perl/s//anything/' input
```